# Write Line: Object reference not set to an instance of an object before each row UiPath

Tags: excel, datatable, global-variables, sequence, uipath-studio

I need assistance of understanding as to why I am getting an error here. Is it because I cannot write line a data table variable because on each row the variable is indeed a data table but on the write line I added a ".toString" at the end. There an alternative?

Also in my previous sequence the read Range is "nonDDContracts" so that it can be passed over to the next sequence which has the each row.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSz2s.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is a very generic .Net Error. This happens when you are trying to execute a method or using a property on the object or value that is null. For example you said you are writing .toString(). Just check using if else that your variable is not null and if it is null then don't do string else do .toString()